# CRM 2011 | Trigger Silverlight function from Javascript Form

Tags: javascript, silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011

I am working on CRM 2011 online.
I have a form and added a Silverlight web-resource to it.
And when a lookup value changes, I need to trigger/invoke a Silverlight function.
I followed this [guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thecrmguys/archive/2011/06/13/making-up-getting-your-dynamics-crm-forms-and-silverlight-web-resources-talking-to-each-other.aspx) exactly and a few other guides with same concept but still not able to run it properly due to this statement:

```
silverlightPlugin.Content.interactionObject.FormAttributeChanged(attName, attValue);
```

I used the IE debugger and found the the **Content** property is always **undefined**.
Why it's undefined ?

Has anyone came across this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question:

The problem was that I was referencing the HTML page instead of the .XAP.

After debugging the Content property was set.